# Why is the Chrome Web Store asking me to give out an email address and physical address publicly on my store page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am curious if anyone else has had these options show up highlighted on the Developer Dashboard. I have been maintaining an extension since September that manages tabs and collects no information.

Highlighted in yellow on the Developer Dashboard:

> Please provide the following information:
>   Physical Address
>   Privacy Policy
>   To ensure a more transparent and positive experience for users, the email address, physical address, and link to your privacy policy that you provide in the developer dashboard will be displayed publicly on your item details page(s) in the Chrome Web Store.
>
> Please provide a current, valid postal address where you may be contacted. If you offer items or in-app purchase items for sale, you may be required to provide a postal address under our developer terms and consumer protection laws; failure to do so may result in the suspension of your account and/or sales of your items. Please ensure that you keep these details up to date if they change. By providing your email or postal address information, you consent to Google publicly displaying or disclosing that information in connection with your items. Learn more

My extension will prompt the user for a donation after 30 days, but it can be disabled. Setting a privacy policy is one thing, but I simply don't have a non-personal address I can give out. Google seems to be mistaking me as a business.

Comment: In addition, my extension uses no external APIs except a link to a Pay Pal donation page.

Comment: Could you post this reply email as an answer instead of a part of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the key phrase in the notification: *"If you offer items or in-app purchase items for sale"*. I believe that means you're not required to give out your addresses if, as in my case, you have a free extension and an app that include "Donate" buttons, and if you're an individual, not a company.

Edit: This looks similar to the German Impressum law. Anyway, it doesn't look mandatory in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Since September 30, 2014. Google has already changed its policies regarding paid app developers. Every developer who opened the developer console starting that date was greeted with a message stating that a physical address must be added in account settings. The change will influence primarily developers who distribute paid apps or allow in-app-purchases.

Visit this [link](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/09/18/google-will-now-require-all-app-publishers-with-paid-apps-or-in-app-purchases-to-have-an-address-on-file-in-google-play/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Update - received this email from Google after asking them what was going on.

> Hi Jason,
>
> In accordance with consumer protection laws and current industry best practices, starting on 3/9/2016 we are implementing a number of changes to product listings in the Chrome Web Store. These changes will ensure a more transparent and positive experience for users. Changes include:
>   As a developer, you must provide a valid email and physical business address where users can contact you directly. The email address and physical business addresses will be displayed on your product details page(s) on the Storefront.
>
> All products that offer in-app purchases to users and/or subscription-based products will have a price range (highest and lowest price) displayed on the ’s product details page in the Chrome Web Store.
>
> You can add an email address and physical business by logging into your developer account in the Chrome Web Store developer dashboard (link).  Please comply within 30 days of receiving a notification on the developer dashboard. If any of your products offer in-app purchases or are subscription based, please go to your developer account to review the prices and publishing status.”

It appears they removed the option to post my address from my account, so it is puzzling they sent this email.